# User defined function isn't printing out max

Tags: php

We have a homework assignment to find the max of three numbers and print them out on our php page. I already got the if statements working, but our teacher wanted us to create a user-defined function to use to find the max. Was hoping to see if someone could find the errors in my if statements of even possibly my function.

```
//input
$n1 = $_POST ['n1'];
$n2 = $_POST ['n2'];
$n3 = $_POST ['n3'];
//data validation
function find_max($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    if (($n1>$n2)&&($n1>$n3)) {
        find_max($n1,$n2,$n3);
    }
    elseif (($n2>$n1)&&($n2>$n3)) {
        find_max($n1,$n2,$n3);
    }
    elseif (($n3>$n1)&&($n3>$n2)) {
        find_max($n1,$n2,$n3);   
    }
    print "Max number entered is ." .find_max($n1,$n2,$n3);
}
```

I've tried adding the function to the if statements, adding singular print commands to each if statements.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php are not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

**Fix to your problem:**

You are not returning a variable or print statements but calling the same functions which is ending up in recursion and infinite loop.
So your code's solution is as follows:

```
function find_max($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    $var = 0; //Variable to store the maximum value initialized to 0
    if (($n1>$n2)&&($n1>$n3)) {
        $var = $n1;
    } elseif (($n2>$n1)&&($n2>$n3)) {
        $var = $n2;
    } elseif (($n3>$n1)&&($n3>$n2)) {
        $var = $n3;   
    }

    print "Max number entered is ." . $var;
}
```

**Optimal Solution:**

```
$n1 = $_POST ['n1'];
$n2 = $_POST ['n2'];
$n3 = $_POST ['n3'];

function find_max($n1, $n2, $n3){
    print "Max number entered is ." . (max($n1, $n2, $n3));
}
```

That's all.

Comment: ps: If that's a homework please don't post here it's supposed to be solved by you and it'll help you in logic building for programming. Only post if you don't know/ can't find something relating to your ``homework``.